# Can't get Latest Rhino Mocks to work

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I don't get it - I've looked at the documentation, and I can't see what's wrong with this code:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var repository = mocks.StrictMock<IRecipeRepository>();
IList<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>();
recipes.Add(new Recipe { ID = 1, Name = "Fish" });
recipes.Add(new Recipe { ID = 2, Name = "Chips" });

// This line doesn't compile:
Expect.Call(() => repository.All()).Return(recipes);
```

This is Rhino Mocks v3.6, for which I can only assume there are breaking changes that aren't in any of the documentation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind - I fixed it:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var repository = mocks.StrictMock<IRecipeRepository>();
IList<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>();
recipes.Add(new Recipe { ID = 1, Name = "Fish" });
recipes.Add(new Recipe { ID = 2, Name = "Chips" });

Expect.Call(repository.All()).Return(recipes);
```

It **is** late, I guess I couldn't see the wood for the trees. :)